# How to create Crystal Reports at the same hierarchy level

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, reporting

I want to create a report for DB like this:
Projects (id, details)
Tasks(id, project_id, details)
Resource(id, task_id, details)
Tools(id, task_id, details)

I using group with projects.id and tasks.id and display data successful but can't suppress if no resources nor tools (header) information. Anybody have the solution, please help me.

Project I

```
Project I details

Task I-1
    Task I-1 details                

    Resource I-1-a         (if tool can display here-
    Resource I-2-b          right of resource is so great)
    Resource I-3-c

    Tool I-1-a
    Tool I-1-b

Task I-1
    Task I-1 details

    Resource I-1-a
    ...

    Tool I-1-a
    ...
```

Project II

```
Project II details

Task II-1
    Task II-1 details

    Resource II-1-a
    Resource II-2-b

    Tool II-1-a
    Tool II-1-b
```

Comment: In the *Section Expert* have you mucked around with `Suppress Blank Section` in your Headers

Comment: Thank you. I have done by using total field and add suppress formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Section Expert* and have a muck around with `Supress Blank Section`

From the docs..

---

#### Suppress Blank Section

The Suppress Blank Section property hides a section whenever there is nothing in it. If something is placed within the section and it produces a value in your report, then it becomes visible